# How to add text to D3 js donut chart

Tags: d3.js

I have the following donut chart here in d3.js

```
Please see here: <https://jsfiddle.net/jz9z9hw1/>
```

I am unsure of how to add text right in the centre of the donut. I'd like it to say "Test System 1".

Also, how does one go about adding text within the arcs? So, it would display the actual numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a text element to your SVG, like this.  I added this to your fiddle, and it added the text right in the middle:

```
  var text = svg.append('text')
   .text('Test System 1')
   .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
```